# Was I correct in accepting this position?

Tags: salary, career-development, new-job, entry-level

I'm a recent college graduate from an IT program at a good state school in the United States. I have my B.S. in Information Technology with an emphasis in web development. The program was fairly coding-intensive.

When I graduated from said University, I applied for a position as a WordPress developer and system administrator for a small marketing/web development company. They offered me 20$/hr for 20 hours a week during the first 3 months and then 22$/hr for full time after that. That corresponds to roughly 41k a year for the 20 hrs a week and roughly 46k a year for the period after that.

The work is GREAT. I have very much enjoyed every single day I've worked since starting (front end web design and development was my ideal job since college), my co-workers are awesome, and I get to learn WP, sys admin, and coding skills one-on-one from a developer with 10+ years of experience.

I'm a little hesitant because I feel like with an IT degree, I could have accepted a position elsewhere for a higher base rate. What do you think? Is the pay outlined pretty good for entry level web development for an employee straight out of college?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the first couple of years you will earn peanuts. Best to stay at a good place that bothers to train you up.

Comment: It's not something that's really answerable here.  The purpose of this site isn't to offer career advice.  Please refer to the [tour help page](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) for information on applicable questions.

Comment: Location is also a huge factor in evaluating compensation.  IT workers in New York City make much more (in the absolute) than those in rural Maine for example.  But when you figure in cost of living, it might not be much of a difference at all.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you were correct, because you have a job and you are growing by learning/mastering new skills and systems.

#### If you enjoy what you are doing, is it really work?

Yes, it is work, but it's better work than when you don't enjoy your job and the people. You have now joined the legions of slightly underemployed people: your situation need not stay that way, but it is good to be enjoying your foray into the work place.

#### The time to look for your next job is while you have one.

Since you look to grow professionally, and of course to grow your earning power, a period while you are enjoying and excelling in work is a good time to begin looking around (discretely since you are new to your job) for the next rung up on professional growth and development.  As often as not we trip over new opportunities, or come across one that's a good fit when we are doing something else.  (My last two jobs happened exactly that way).

#### Make sure that the next job you go to is: something you are going *to*

If you are enjoying your current job environment, good.  Anything  you do if it involves mastering a new challenge helps you to grow professionally.  Your current positive attitude will likely come across during any interview you do for your next step in your professional growth.

#### Bottom line: keep a positive attitude, enjoy your current challenge, look for your next challenge.